# 1 Google Analytics account or top-level domain + profiles for sub-domains vs. 1 account for each sub-domain

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

We have the following websites

- An online magazine Singapore edition - `sg.abc.com`
- The same online magazine Malaysia edition - `my.abc.com`
- Forums around the same subjects as the online magazine but functions independently - `forums.abc.com`
- Classifieds site rather also around the same subjects but functions independently - `directory.abc.com`

Each of the above websites currently has its own Google Analytics account.
`abc.com` has a separate Google Analytics account too.
`sg.abc.com` has the most traffic and generates most revenues

Are there any practical benefits of merging all the above sub-domains to be under abc.com?
I can think of more reliable analytics and consistency for sure.

Are there more? cross-sales?

Answer (score 1):

I would use multiple profiles since you can gather custom reports from all the profiles

http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/fnjRGuMfAB0/jhEL5Wr3rhMJ

Google has offered API since 2009. See the Google Analytics App Gallery for products that you can use to consolidate traffic from multiple profiles. One such product is NExt Analytics for Excel and a sample report they supply handles multiple profiles.

http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/about?app_id=93002